# Why are lower respiratory infections so prevalent in undeveloped countries?

Tags: infection, disease-transmission, lungs, infectious-diseases, respiratory-system

As you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_respiratory_tract_infection#/media/File:Lower_respiratory_infections_world_map-Deaths_per_million_persons-WHO2012.svg), lower respiratory infections are a major cause of death in undeveloped and developing countries, especially in central Africa.  What are the primary causes of lower respiratory infections in these countries?  Is it from smoke inhalation, unsanitary water, close proximity to one another without proper medical care, or some other factor I'm not thinking of?